# i have a list of string like (10) and (10) and so on and i need to remove that and add the numbers in the list, how can i do that

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have Extracted a String List from Web page through selenium webdriver in this way

> (10) (10) (8) (5) (4) (4) (3) (3) (3) (1) (1) (1) (1) (1)

When I write this type of code it is printing the below results

```
for(int m=0;m<IndPro.size();m++){
            System.out.println(IndPro.get(m));
        }
```

> (10)
>   (10)
>   (8)
>   (5)
>   (4)
>   (4)
>   (3)
>   (3)
>   (3)
>   (1)
>   (1)
>   (1)
>   (1)
>   (1)

When i write this type of code

```
for (int m=0;m<IndPro.size();m++){
            String[] Z = IndPro.get(m).split("\\(");
            System.out.println(Z);
        }
```

it is giving some error

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're splitting the value into an array which you output, giving output something like;

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@511d50c0
```

What you want is probably to get the second value in the resulting array, the number;

```
String[] Z = IndPro.get(m).split("\\(|\\)");
System.out.println(Z[1]);
```

Another alternative would be to use `substring` to remove the first and last character;

```
String value = IndPro.get(m);
value = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
System.out.println(value);
```